# View Controller Segue from didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swift

Trying to set up 4 different segues that are triggered from 4 different cells in a `UITableView` to segue to different view controllers in my app. My main menu is embedded in a navigation controller. I setup the segues by control dragging from the main menu view controller to my 4 different view controllers. Then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I switch the `indexPath`.row and instantiate my segues from this method. The problem I'm running into is a **SIGABRT** crash when the segue is performed. `prepareForSegue` is called so I know the segue is being triggered but it's causing a crash that I can't seem to figure out. Code posted below, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    switch(indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            break;

        case 1:
        {

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController" sender:self];
            //Also tried passing in the cell for the parameter "sender:" but this
            //doesnt work either. 

           break;
        }

        //Other segues would be performed in a similar manner. 

        case 2:
            break;

        case 3:
            break;

        case 4:
            break;

        case 5:
            break;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Are your segues connected from the tableview to their destinations? This might be the problem (it was for me anyway) Try connecting the segues from your owning view controller (i.e. The view controller that contains your tableview) to the destination view controllers. Hope this helps.

Comment: Where it states that a SIGABRT has occurred could you share the actual exception - as in, what exactly caused the crash? Also if you go to the corresponding segue in your storyboard, is it named SecondViewController? If it's not, that's probably the problem - it's trying to perform a segue that does not exist.

Comment: @Gismay Yes, the segues are connected from the view controller that contains the tableView. It must be something else that is causing the problem.

Comment: @mMo Ah I think I might have more information. I had my console closed for some reason and didn't think about it but from the console here is what is displayed on the exception: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'SecondViewController'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your segue is configured as a "push" segue. This means that an instance of `SecondViewController` would be pushed on to a Navigation Controller's navigation stack. (See [Push Segues on Apple's storyboard tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html).)

However, your table view controller isn't inside a navigation controller, so this is impossible. (There's no stack of view controllers to push on to.)

Your simple choices:

- Change your segue to "Show" (in Xcode 6), or "Modal" (in Xcode 5)
- Embed your Table View Controller in a Navigation Controller, so there's a stack to push on to

More complex solutions involve building custom parent view controllers and defining custom transitions, but I'm assuming that's not what you're after.

---

Some unrelated general information:

- Your attempt to change the "sender" doesn't matter. All "sender" does is allow you to pass any object you want into the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method. This parameter is otherwise ignored.
- When you get a crash, you should always read the console, and the stack trace. If you can't figure this out, include them on your Stack Overflow question. [My App Crashed, Now What?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) is excellent reading if you're new to debugging this stuff.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I guess the problem too might be that I'm not using a UITableViewController rather I'm using a UIViewController with a tableView inside of the UIViewController. I've added an image showing how the storyboard is configured.